# Show only the specific indexed array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I show only the specific index? For example, here's my UI.

[image]

As you can see in the picture I have 3 checkboxes and 3 textboxes with array value.

Let's say these are the name of the element.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]">
<input type="text" name="textbox[]">
```

Then print the array:

```
$check = $_POST['check'];
$total_rec = $_POST['textbox'];

echo 'Check Array<br>';
print_r($check);

echo '<br<br><br><br>';
echo 'TextBox Array<br>';
print_r($textbox);
```

Result:

```
Check Array
Array ( [0] => 2 ) 

TextBox Array
Array ( [0] => [1] => 2 [2] => )
```

As you can see in textbox array all index showed, all I want is to show only the specific index with value and that is the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEB7z.jpg) => 2 only.

Answer (score 0):

use **empty()**, return **true** if contain value, example :

```
 //iterate each $total_rec's member
foreach($total_rec as each){
    //if $each not empty, do something
    if(!empty($each)){
        echo $each;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$total_rec` for post values of both `checkbox` and `text`. You can filter the array of text input like this:

```
$total_rec_text = $_POST['textbox'];
$total_rec_text = array_filter($total_rec_text, function($arr){
    return !empty($arr) ? true : false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over `$_POST` array and check if checkbox is checked.

If checked, then only, get/print value.

> Also, in HTML, you need to add specific counters to both checboxes and
>   textboxes.
>
> As only checked checboxes get posted and texboxes get posted by
>   default.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[0]">
<input type="text" name="textbox[0]">

<input type="checkbox" name="check[1]">
<input type="text" name="textbox[1]">

<input type="checkbox" name="check[2]">
<input type="text" name="textbox[2]">


if (isset($_POST['check'])) {
 foreach ($_POST['check'] as $idx => $value) {
  echo "<br/>" . $_POST['check'][$idx] . ' ' . $_POST['textbox'][$idx];
 }
}
```